# ASP.NET CORE Deployment Issue: aspnetcorev2.dll failed to load

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment, http-status-code-503

I am facing one issue after deploying my ASP.NET Core solution to IIS.

Issue: After deployment, when I browse the site, it shows *503 - Server Unavailable*. The application pool gets automatically stopped. In the event Viewer logs I found the below error:

> The Module DLL .......\aspnetcorev2.dll failed to load. The data is the error.

My ASP.NET Core MVC project is built in .NET Core 3.1 version. Used Folder profile to publish.

After successful publishing, I copied all the files to the Web server *C:\inetpub\wwwroot[MY_PROJECT_FOLDER]*

Web Server Details:
Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit

Softwares installed in the web server:
[Control Panel Programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGpZD.png)

I see there are similar posts on this issue but the provided solutions didn't work. So created this new post. Kindly let me know your valuable comments to solve my issue. If you need additional information please let me know.

Comment: Please run some diagnostics and paste the report as part of your question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the errors typically indicates that there is something wrong with the Asp.Net Core runtime, which causing the failure of hosting the Asp.net Core solution.
I strongly recommend you install the corresponding IIS Hosting Bundle based on your Asp.net Core version. It includes the .NET Core Runtime and IIS support.
[image]
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

> After deployment, when I browser the site, it shows 503 - Server
>   Unavailable. The application pool gets automatically stopped.

If you changed the Application pool identity to a specific account, please ensure that the username/password is correct. Otherwise, please restore the setting to built-in account. Incorrect credential will prevent the application pool running when we start to access the website(credentials can be erroneously set up by Powershell and some other IIS API).
Also, try to set “Enable 32-Bit application” to true in the Advanced settings of IIS application pool.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.